# How to convert unicode point to Emoji || Symbol || Character

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to convert Unicode Code Points Notation like "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8" to "".

In javaScript, what I have tried so far is

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("U+1F1FA", 16));
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: you can use `String.fromCodePoint('0x1f1fa', '0x1f1f8')` to get `us`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static method [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) to achieve this.

```js
const us = String.fromCodePoint('0x1F1FA', '0x1F1F8');
console.log(us);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the hex code in braces like this:

```
console.log('\u{1f1fa}\u{1f1f8}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for above answers. I came with a method to convert the unicode notations to Emoji.

```
        function unicodeToChar(text:string) {
            const splited = text.split(" ")
            let str = ""
            for(let i = 0;i < splited.length;i++){
                splited[i] = splited[i].replace('U','0')
                splited[i] = splited[i].replace('+','x')
                str += String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(splited[i],16))
            }
            return str
        }
```